# Conversion or cast of Glib::RefPtr<T> to Gtk::Widget& needed

Tags: c++, g++, gtkmm, glibmm

**I have trouble to convert a Glib::RefPtr into a GtkWidget, with T derived from Widget:**

```
#include <gtkmm/drawingarea.h>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/fixed.h>

class MyPic : public Gtk::DrawingArea {
public:
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Gtk::Fixed f;

    Gtk::DrawingArea da; // this works.
    Gtk::DrawingArea mp; // this works.
    Glib::RefPtr<MyPic> rp_mp; // this not.

    f.put(da, 10, 20);
    f.put(mp, 10, 30);
    f.put(rp_mp, 10, 40); // Line # 19
}
```

This does not compile:

```
joerg> g++ x.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`
x.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
x.cpp:19:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘Gtk::Fixed::put(Glib::RefPtr<MyPic>&, int, int)’
x.cpp:19:24: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/fixed.h:123:8: note: void Gtk::Fixed::put(Gtk::Widget&, int, int)
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/fixed.h:123:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Glib::RefPtr<MyPic>’ to ‘Gtk::Widget&’

joerg> g++ --version
```

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Glib::RefPtr is a smart pointer, and [DrawingArea](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1DrawingArea.html) is derived from Widget, so this should work.

Dereferencing (like `f.put(*rp_mp,...)` ) is intentionally not working. The documentation states: ["*Unlike most other smart pointers, RefPtr doesn't support dereferencing through * object_ptr.*"](http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/classGlib_1_1RefPtr.html)

How do I get a **Widget&** from the **SmartPtr**?

Comment: What about dereferencing it??

Comment: dereferencing (like f.put(*rp_mp,10,40) ) will not work and is documented to not work "Unlike most other smart pointers, RefPtr doesn't support dereferencing through * object_ptr.", from http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/classGlib_1_1RefPtr.html. I added it to the Question.

Comment: That's a really odd behavior for s.th. called a 'smart pointer', but if it's like this, it is.

Comment: The question is why you have a `RefPtr` of a widget in the first place.  `RefPtr` is designed for pooled resources, not widgets.

Comment: This is a striped down example, the real code is longer. I used this RefPtr, because I collect the Widgets in a `std::vector`. It's a Gtk::Fixed with a flexible number of Thumbnail Pictures, realized as a Derived Widget (from DrawingArea).

So, if you could suggest a better way to put a variing number of my widgets in a Container, that would help also.

Comment: @JörgBeyer The maintainer of gtkmm is on record as stating that `Glib::RefPtr` is not meant as a smart pointer, or any case except when the API forces you to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29156111/2757035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I suspect you can design around the need, you can dereference e.g. `Glib::RefPtr foo` as follows:

```
some_method_needing_a_reference(*foo.operator->())
```